# Windowsでpyppeteerを実行したら、「このアプリケーションのサイド バイ サイド構成が正しくないため、アプリケーションを開始できませんでした。」というエラーが発生しました。

Tags: python, pyppeteer

## 環境

- pyppeteer 1.0.2
- Python 3.9.13
- Windows11 Pro(22H2, 22621.1194)

## 問題

以下のコードを実行したら、「このアプリケーションのサイド バイ サイド構成が正しくないため、アプリケーションを開始できませんでした。」というエラーが発生しました。

```
import os
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
from pyppeteer.page import Page
from typing import Optional
import time

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)-8s : %(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():
    logger.info("start 'launch()'")
    browser: Browser = await launch()
    logger.info("start 'newPage()'")
    page: Page = await browser.newPage()
    logger.info("start 'goto()'")
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
    title = await page.title()
    logger.info(f"title='{title}'")
    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Downloads> python sample.py
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 12:15:08,341 : asyncio : Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO     : 2023-02-10 12:15:08,342 : __main__ : start 'launch()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\sample.py", line 28, in <module>
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\sample.py", line 18, in main
    browser: Browser = await launch()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 307, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 148, in launch
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 14001] このアプリケーションのサイド バイ サイド構成が正しくないため、アプリケーションを開始できませんでした。詳細については、アプリケーションのイベント ログを参照するか、コマンド ライン ツール sxstrace.exe を使用してくだ さい。
```

## 質問

上記のエラーは何が原因で、どのように対応すればよいでしょうか？

## 補足

- 2023/02/10時点で、Windows Updateは最新の状態です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pythonの公式サイト](https://www.python.org/downloads/)からPython3.11.2をインストールして実行したところ、問題なく実行できました。

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Downloads> python sample.py
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:41,984 : __main__ : start 'launch()'
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:42,504 : pyppeteer.launcher : Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:53570/devtools/browser/049dcc71-c6c3-4f4c-845f-154d0e97a772
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:42,507 : __main__ : start 'newPage()'
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:42,636 : __main__ : start 'goto()'
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:44,347 : __main__ : title='Google'
INFO     : 2023-02-17 11:51:44,348 : pyppeteer.launcher : terminate chrome process...
```

※ログはINFOレベル以上